# What must the distance between two circles be such that they represent independent events.

Tags: probability, geometry, recreational-mathematics

A sample space $P$ is represented by a rectangle with width $5$ and height $4$. Two events $A$ and $B$ are represented by two circles with radii $1$ and $\sqrt2$ respectively.

What must the distance $d$ between the centers of the two circles be for the two events to be independent?

[image: Figure]

Comment: What's your probability distribution? The normalised Lesbegue measure?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I'm not sure what you mean. But the probability of an event occuring is given by how much area it takes up in the sample space.

Comment: So, the probability of an event is area divided by $20$. Well, do you know how to calculate area of the intersection?